# loop to get values from php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array which contents are;

```
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [type] => 1
    )
[shops] => Array
    (
        [basead] => Array
            (
                [shop] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => KN0100060500211230
                                [entryname] => 陽陽ラーメン本店東栄店
                                [searchnum] => 7187766
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => KN0114102400000170
                                [entryname] => 炭火焼肉たんたん
                                [searchnum] => 7187766
                            )
                    )

            )

    )
```

I have this code to get the values I wanted;

```
foreach ( $hascompany as $company ) {
            $companyId = $company['shops']['basead']['shop']['id'];
            $entryName = $company['shop']['basead']['shop']['entryname'];
            $priority = $company['shop']['basead']['shop']['priority'];
            $searchNum = $company['shop']['basead']['shop']['searchNum'];
}
```

How can I do loop to get the values I want from the array List?

Comment: by doing a foreach on `$company['shops']['basead']['shop']` I should think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
foreach ( $hascompany['shops']['basead']['shop'] as $company ) {
            $companyId = $company['id'];
            $entryName = $company['entryname'];
            $searchNum = $company['searchNum'];
}
```

Comment: what if the data returned has only 1 <shop>? how should I do the loop? because this gives an error?

Comment: put condition before it like if(is_array($hascompany['shops']['basead']['shop'])){ loop here } else { single record code here }

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    foreach ( $hascompany['shops']['basead']['shop'] as $shop ) {

         $companyId = $shop['id'];
         $entryName = $shop['entryname'];
         $priority = $shop['priority'];
         $searchNum = $shop['searchNum'];

    }
```